# Append new extension when copying files

Tags: powershell, pipe, copy-item

I use the following command in order to locate the files that are greater than 900KB in a specific folder:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\[some folder] | where { ($_.Length /1KB) -gt 900 }
```

I want to pipe the results in a `Copy-Item` command in order to copy the results in the folder `desktop\images` and add to each file the .jpg extension (they don't have extensions in the source).

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append the new extension to the name:

```
... | Copy-Item -Destination { Join-Path 'desktop\images' ($_.Name + '.jpg') }
```

Comment: haha, are you tyring to copy the lock screen images for windows background?